# C#: Passing null to overloaded method - which method is called?

Tags: c#, null, overloading

Say I have two overloaded versions of a C# method:

```
void Method( TypeA a ) { }
void Method( TypeB b ) { }
```

I call the method with:

```
Method( null );
```

Which overload of the method is called? What can I do to ensure that a particular overload is called?

Comment: Another one to be aware of is overloaded methods where at least one method uses the params keyword.

Answer (score 75, accepted):

It depends on `TypeA` and `TypeB`.

- If exactly one of them is applicable (e.g. there is no conversion from `null` to `TypeB` because it's a value type but `TypeA` is a reference type) then the call will be made to the applicable one.
- Otherwise it depends on the relationship between `TypeA` and `TypeB`.

  - If there is an implicit conversion from `TypeA` to `TypeB` but no implicit conversion from `TypeB` to `TypeA` then the overload using `TypeA` will be used.
  - If there is an implicit conversion from `TypeB` to `TypeA` but no implicit conversion from `TypeA` to `TypeB` then the overload using `TypeB` will be used.
  - Otherwise, the call is ambiguous and will fail to compile.

See section 7.4.3.4 of the C# 3.0 spec for the detailed rules.

Here's an example of it not being ambiguous. Here `TypeB` derives from `TypeA`, which means there's an implicit conversion from `TypeB` to `TypeA`, but not vice versa. Thus the overload using `TypeB` is used:

```
using System;

class TypeA {}
class TypeB : TypeA {}

class Program
{
    static void Foo(TypeA x)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Foo(TypeA)");
    }

    static void Foo(TypeB x)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Foo(TypeB)");
    }

    static void Main()
    {
        Foo(null); // Prints Foo(TypeB)
    }
}
```

In general, even in the face of an otherwise-ambiguous call, to ensure that a particular overload is used, just cast:

```
Foo((TypeA) null);
```

or

```
Foo((TypeB) null);
```

Note that if this involves inheritance in the declaring classes (i.e. one class is overloading a method declared by its base class) you're into a whole other problem, and you need to cast the target of the method rather than the argument.

Comment: @Jon: Why is the behavior as you describe in the case an implicit conversion is available? I would rather have expected the opposite. Is it just a matter of definition?

Comment: @divo: It's definitely a design decision, but probably the reason behind it is that TypeB method is pretty much a specialized case of TypeA method. I mean, for every valid arg, by default TypeA will be matched unless the object is known to be TypeB.
This behavior for null ensures this consistency.

Comment: Mehrdad is right - if you can convert from TypeB to TypeA, then TypeB is more specific than TypeA, so will be picked in preference.

Comment: Casting would help compiler to figure out which version to call, that's neat.

Answer (score 8):

Jon Skeet has given a comprehensive answer, but from a design point of view you shouldn't depend on corner-cases of the compiler specification. If nothing else, if you have to look up what it does before you write it, the next person to try to read it won't know what it does either. It's not maintainable.

Overloads are there for convenience, and two different overloads with the same name should do the same thing. If the two methods do different things, rename one or both of them.

It's more usual for an overloaded method to have variants with varying numbers of parameters, and for the overload with less parameters to supply sensible defaults.

e.g. `string ToString(string format, System.IFormatProvider provider)` has the most parameters,
`string ToString(System.IFormatProvider provider)` supplies a default format, and
`string ToString()` supplies a default format and provider,

Comment: I don't see your point about overloads. True, overloads should do the same thing, but may do it in different ways. That's why you want overloads. The number of arguments is irrelevant, and may be the same or different (case in point: the various Convert methods). About the compiler spesifics: depending on the skill level of the next person, anything may be a «corner case». So long as your design makes sense, and works in the intuitive way, it does it's job. That may require careful consideration design-time, not so much when the class is used later.

Comment: I think the point he's making is that the most typical use of overloads is to perform some function on data that may include different types or may include more or fewer parameters.

In fact, I've written a handful of overloads where the one's with fewer parameters actually have all the same data (strings) in fewer disparate pieces.  In that case they call the higher overload after breaking the pieces apart and providing them again.

Answer (score 5):

Jon Skeet already answered which overload gets chosen by default, but if you want to ensure that particular overload is called, it is often better to use named parameters than cast.

If you have:

```
void Method( TypeA a ) { }
void Method( TypeB b ) { }
```

You can call `Method(a: null);` or `Method(b: null);`

Answer (score 1):

ambigous call. (compile time error).

Comment: hi,
I tried following sample and did not get compile error; any thoughts why?
 class Program
    {
        void test1(ICollection<String> a)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("test1-ICollection");
        }
        void test1(IList<String> a)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("test1-List");
        }
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Program p = new Program();
            p.test1(null);
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }

Comment: but I got compile error when I changed one of the overloads to accept a parameter of type IComparer<String>

    class Program
    {
        
        void test1(IList<String> a)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("test1-List");
        }
        void test1(IComparer<String> a)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("test1-IComparer");
        }
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Program p = new Program();
            p.test1(null);
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution is to create another method with the signature of:

```
void Method() { }
```

or better to update the signature on one of the methods to be:

```
void Method( TypeB b = null ) { }
```

and then call it as so:

```
Method();
```

At compile time the value `null` is untyped and so the compiler can't match it up with one of the method signatures.  At run time any variable that might resolve to `null` will still be typed and so it won't cause a problem.

Answer (score -1):

Just type cast it to what you want the overloaded value to be

```
void method(int);
void method(string);
method((string) null){};
```

This will call the