# Method overloading and null value

Tags: c#

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [C#: Passing null to overloaded method - which method is called?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/719546/c-passing-null-to-overloaded-method-which-method-is-called)

Consider these 2 methods:

```
void Method(object obj)  { Console.WriteLine("object"); }
void Method(int[] array) { Console.WriteLine("int[]"); }
```

When I try calling:

```
Method(null);
```

in Visual Studio 2008 SP1 I get `int[]`.

Why is this?

Comment: He might be asking why the compiler favors that overload.

Comment: His question is why does overload resolution resolve null to the method that takes an int array rather than the one that takes object.

Comment: See this question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/719546/25727

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/719546/c-passing-null-to-overloaded-method-which-method-is-called

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It is a product of overload resolution. Your argument, `null`, is convertible to both `object` and `int[]`. The compiler therefore picks the most specific version, because `int[]` is more specific than `object`.

Comment: +1: "More specific" being defined as "an `int[]` can be implicitly cast to an `object`, but an `object` cannot be implicitly cast to an `int[]`."

Answer (score 2):

Because int[] is more specific than object, the method with the object-parameter will be ignored. If you would call Method("Some string"), the method with the object-parameter will be called.