# Changing the name just because of Null?

Tags: c#, api

I work on developing an external API. I added a method to my public interface :

```
public void AddMode(TypeA mode);
public void AddMode(TypeB mode); // the new method, TypeB and TypeA are not related at all
```

It looked good, until one test broke that was passing a `null` . That made the compiler confused with ambiguous call. I fixed the test with casting the null.

However my question is :

- Should I change the name just because of this?
- Or should let the client do the cast as I did? (if they pass null for whatever reason)

What is the best in this case while designing APIs ?

**Edit** :

the call was like this **AddMode(null)** , not like :

```
TypeA vl = null; 
AddMode(v1); // this doesn't cause a problem
```

Comment: Similar issue here [passing null](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/719546/c-passing-null-to-overloaded-method-which-method-is-called) and cast is recommended (an excellent answer)

Comment: @MBen - I suggest to change name of methods.

Comment: @V4Vendetta I saw that before posting :-). However I am wondering for the usability of the API, if I should let the client maybe fall into this. I don't see why they would call those method with null, but who know :-)

Comment: @AVD that's what I am favoring.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

An API should be designed so that it's easy to use correctly and hard to use incorrectly.
Your API is easy to use correctly:

```
AddMode(new TypeA());
```

does compile.

It's harder to use incorrectly:

```
AddMode(null);
```

does not compile. The user ist forced to do something like

```
AddMode((TypeA)null);
```

Which should make him think, whether this is expected usage. So I think your API is OK as it is.

Comment: I like this. I didn't see it from this perspective.

Answer (score 1):

I think that depends on how exceptional `null` as a value for the respective argument is.

Compare, for example, [this `ArgumentNullException` constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms130823.aspx): It is most frequently called when an internal exception has to be set. Otherwise, [this constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wssa019h.aspx), which excepts the name of the illegal argument, is passed. On odd occasions, the former has to be invoked because a custom message has to be supplied, but no internal exception is supplied (I usually do this when I'm throwing the exception for an array/collection argument that contains `null`, but is not `null` itself). So, in this case, I need the explicit cast, and I'd say it is acceptable there.

If your methods really do the same, but `null` is still a usual value, you might want to add a parameterless overload for the `null` variant (i.e. the explicit cast is still possible, but users can also call the parameterless overload instead).

If your methods do something somewhat different, and yet something else for `null`, you can think about disallowing `null` altogether for the methods you've shown and adding a parameterless overload for the `null` case.

**Update:** If `null` is not acceptable anyway (and will result in an exception), then you should leave the method as it is. Other than for testing purposes, there should never be any whatsoever situation in which a literal `null` would be passed to the method, as this will invariably yield an exception. Therefore, do not change your overload names in this case.

Comment: But null is not acceptable, I throw an ArgumentNullException in both method. However the error I see is at compiler time when passing null like this Addmode(null)

Answer (score 0):

Is null valid input to this method anyway?

Personally I'd leave it as is as long as both overloads of AddMode related, since you'd expect AddMode(X) and AddMode(Y) to be doing something related to each other.

If they are not related in any way, then maybe a method name change is in order

Answer (score 0):

Well, it depends either `null` value is *acceptable* value in your API.

If not just do not accept it, by not supporting it. So even if the consumer will *try* to use it with `null` the compiler will break on ambiguity problem.

Comment: Well the null is not acceptable, but the error is at compiler time.

Comment: @MBen: you don't want that it's compile time ?

Comment: @MBen: if passing a null is **not** supposed behaviour of the consumer of your API, inside, in case of recieving null raise an exception, and function definitions leave as is, **imo**.

Comment: Yes I do that. My question is more should I defend my self from having a call Like : AddMode(null) just because the compiler gets confused which method to call.

Comment: @MBen: **imo** no, the *caller* has to specify which overload *exactly* it going to call.

Answer (score 0):

If your API accepts a null as a possible parameter value, then you have to specify it in the documentation and mention it is necessary to cast it, and write some code samples to show how.

However, if you don not want the user to use null values, you might change TypeA and TypeB as a `struct` instead of a `class`, if your class design allow it.