# Why does casting null to type for method selection work?

Tags: c#, compile-time-constant

According to the answer to [C#: Passing null to overloaded method - which method is called?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/719566/1964861), nulls seem to carry type information. In fact, I can also use

```
class Program
{
    static void Method(TypeA a)
    {
        Console.Write("Output of Method(TypeA a):");
        Console.WriteLine(a); // Prints nothing, on account of the null.
    }
    static void Method(TypeB b)
    {
        Console.Write("Output of Method(TypeB b):");
        Console.WriteLine(b); // Also prints nothing, on account of the null.
    }
    static void Main()
    {
        var a = (TypeA)null;
        var b = (TypeB)null;
        Method(a);
        Method(b);
    }
}
class TypeA { }
class TypeB { }
```

Which yields

> Output of Method(TypeA a):
>  Output of Method(TypeB b):

What's going on here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, the null itself doesn't carry the type information. The cast *just* tells the compiler what the type of the variables `a` and `b` should be... it can't tell without the cast, because `null` is convertible to any reference type or nullable type.

The types of those variables are then used in overload resolution. Don't forget that the choice here is simply made at compile-time - it doesn't involve the execution-time value of the argument at all.

Your code is precisely equivalent to:

```
TypeA a = null;
TypeB b = null;
Method(a);
Method(b);
```

If you used *dynamic* typing, so that the overload resolution was performed at execution-time instead, you'd get a failure:

```
dynamic foo = (TypeA) null; // Or without the cast. It makes no difference.
Method(foo); // RuntimeBinderException at execution time, due to ambiguity
```

Answer (score 1):

While the case presented is obvious, I stumbled upon some odd behaviour involving dynamic casts. Have a look at the program below:

```
class Base { }
class Child : Base { }

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Base node = GetChild();
        Test((dynamic) node);

        node = GetBase();
        Test((dynamic) node);
    }

    static Child GetChild()
    {
        return null;
    }
    static Base GetBase()
    {
        return null;
    }

    // Guess how many times each method is called..
    static void Test(Base node)
    {
        // Nope!
    }

    static void Test(Child child)
    {
        // It's this one twice.
    }
}
```

Inspecting the code with .NET reflector resulted in a crash (Ambiguous Match), but dotPeek provided a closer look at the generated IL (decompiled here):

```
private static void Main(string[] args)
{
  Base base1 = (Base) Program.GetChild();
  if (Program.<Main>o__SiteContainer0.<>p__Site1 == null)
    Program.<Main>o__SiteContainer0.<>p__Site1 = CallSite<Action<CallSite, Type, object>>.Create(Binder.InvokeMember(CSharpBinderFlags.ResultDiscarded, "Test", (IEnumerable<Type>) null, typeof (Program), (IEnumerable<CSharpArgumentInfo>) new CSharpArgumentInfo[2]
    {
      CSharpArgumentInfo.Create(CSharpArgumentInfoFlags.UseCompileTimeType | CSharpArgumentInfoFlags.IsStaticType, (string) null),
      CSharpArgumentInfo.Create(CSharpArgumentInfoFlags.None, (string) null)
    }));
  Program.<Main>o__SiteContainer0.<>p__Site1.Target((CallSite) Program.<Main>o__SiteContainer0.<>p__Site1, typeof (Program), (object) base1);

  Base base2 = Program.GetBase();
  if (Program.<Main>o__SiteContainer0.<>p__Site2 == null)
    Program.<Main>o__SiteContainer0.<>p__Site2 = CallSite<Action<CallSite, Type, object>>.Create(Binder.InvokeMember(CSharpBinderFlags.ResultDiscarded, "Test", (IEnumerable<Type>) null, typeof (Program), (IEnumerable<CSharpArgumentInfo>) new CSharpArgumentInfo[2]
    {
      CSharpArgumentInfo.Create(CSharpArgumentInfoFlags.UseCompileTimeType | CSharpArgumentInfoFlags.IsStaticType, (string) null),
      CSharpArgumentInfo.Create(CSharpArgumentInfoFlags.None, (string) null)
    }));
  Program.<Main>o__SiteContainer0.<>p__Site2.Target((CallSite) Program.<Main>o__SiteContainer0.<>p__Site2, typeof (Program), (object) base2);
}
```

I kind of understand the dynamic call site construction, and the fact that two variables are used (base1 and base2) while the source uses only one could be due to optimization. However, that base2 variable has nothing to do with the Child type! It is declared as a variable of type Base and initialized with null from a function with Base prototype.

Adding another class and handler method does what you might or might not expect by throwing a runtime exception "The call is ambiguous between the following methods or properties: 'Program.Test(Child)' and 'Program.Test(AnotherChild)'". This exception is thrown on both the first and the second dynamic cast, which is to be expected as it is similar code.

```
class AnotherChild : Base { }
static void Test(AnotherChild child)
{
    // Ambiguous between AnotherChild and Child -> Runtime Exception
}
```

In other words, it seems that regardless of type, a dynamic cast on a null object will traverse the inheritance tree bottom-up and gives up when it finds multiple types on that level.. As a conformation of the above, having AnotherChild inherit from Child indeed does invoke the AnotherChild handler.

```
class AnotherChild : Child { }
```

To be honest I think it should be illegal to do a dynamic cast on a null object, would be much better if that threw every time. When you're doing dynamic casts you're likely also using method overloads; this just seems like a silent killer in the making.

Answer (score 0):

When you write `var`, the compiler is determining what type the variable is based on what you are assigning it.

By doing an explicit (C-Style) cast, you are saying "This is what this type is" and `var` picks that up, causing the overloads to work as displayed.

Assigning "null" is a valid value for any reference type (so of course that compiles), but the type information is provided by the cast.

Answer (score 0):

> nulls seem to carry type information

No, the *variable* has a type.  `null` is just `null`.  *Which* method is called is determined at compile-time.  When you do this:

```
var a = (TypeA)null;     
var b = (TypeB)null;
Method(a);
Method(b);
```

The compiler *binds* `Method(a)` to `Method(TypeA)` because you use a varaible of type `TypeA` in the call.  Same goes for `Method(b)`.  The question you reference explains the binding in better detail.

To prove that `null` carries no type information, add a third call that defers the method binding to run-time:

```
static void Main()
{
    var a = (TypeA)null;
    var b = (TypeB)null;
    dynamic c = a;
    Method(a);
    Method(b);
    Method(c);   // will throw a `RuntimeBinderException` since the type of c can't be determined at run-time.
}
```