# Testing GET/POST methods in controller with same name in ASP.MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, unit-testing

I have two methods

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Edit(int? id)
{
   // do stuff
   return View();
}
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Edit(Object object)
{
  //do more stuff
  return View();
}
```

I am trying to Test this methods, For example I want to pass `null` to controller and I get ambiguity error.

```
var controller = new Controller();
controller.Edit(null); // ambiguity error
```

How can I distinguish that I want to call GET or POST method?

Comment: what url are you using to request the Edit page?

Comment: @DavidLee OP isn't using URLs, this is unit testing

Comment: @DavidG Thats why you're the G, completely missed that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can also use the parameterize the calls.

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Edit(int? id)
{
   return View();
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Edit(Object myObject)
{
  return View();
}
```

.

```
var controller = new Controller();

controller.Edit(myObject: null);
controller.Edit(id: null);
```

Comment: I think this is most elegant solution, In such case that you don't have arguments with same names

Answer (score 1):

There is a really good explaination on this at [C#: Passing null to overloaded method - which method is called?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/719546/c-passing-null-to-overloaded-method-which-method-is-called)

Base on that, I think casting it should work

```
controler.Edit((int?) null); // for int
controler.Edit((object) null); // for object
```

Answer (score 1):

If you explicitly declare your parameter then the compiler will be able to more specifically determine the type when passing a `null` value:

```
var controller = new Controller();

int? argInt = null;
var getResult = controler.Edit(argInt);

object argObj = null;
var postResult = controller.Edit(argObj);
```