# why string overloaded method is called over a object overlodaded method when the parameter is null

Tags: c#, .net

Here is sample code as mentioned below

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Program prgm = new Program();
        string sprgm = prgm.OverloadedMethod(null);
        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    private string OverloadedMethod(object arg)
    {
        return "object as parameter";
    }

    private string OverloadedMethod(string arg)
    {
        return "string as parameter ";
    }
}
```

when i pass null as parameter. it is the acceptable value for both string overloaded menthod and object overloaded method but why string overloaded method is called?

Comment: Nice detailed discussion here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/719546/c-passing-null-to-overloaded-method-which-method-is-called

Comment: thanks a lot i will check out the link

Comment: Another [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5173339/how-does-the-method-overload-resolution-system-decide-which-method-to-call-when).

Comment: he has arg different so compiles ok

Comment: @John indeed, your dup is even better. Added it.