# Null handling in `IEquatable.Equals` in a C# Struct

Tags: c#, struct

I haven't used C# for a while after using Java for years. So I just (re-)learned that a `struct` is a non-nullable value type. So far so good.

I have a `struct Coordinate` implementing `IEquatable`:

```
public struct Coordinate : IEquatable<Coordinate>
{

    public Coordinate(double x, double y, Projection proj)
    {
        this.X = x;
        this.Y = y;
        this.Proj = proj;
    }

    public double X { get; }
    public double Y { get; }
    public Projection Proj { get; }

    public bool Equals(Coordinate other)
    {
        return X == other.X && Y == other.Y && Proj == other.Proj;
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return $"x={X}, y={Y}, projection={Proj}";
    }

}
```

I get a compiler warning not allowing me to implement a `null` check (`other != null`) in `Equals(Coordinate)` but I can call `ltown.Equals(null)` returning `false`:

```
Coordinate ltown = new Coordinate(-65.17, 44.88, Projection.Mercator);
Console.WriteLine(ltown.Equals(null)); // prints false
```

Why is the application not crashing when passing `null`?
What's the magic here? It does crash if I implement Coordinate as a class instead of a struct. That's what I would expect here too.

---

**UPDATE**

Etienne de Martel provides the correct answer. I have asked overhasty and should have known it. However, I got distracted with `IEquatable` and **the fact that a class and a struct behaved differently**. Regarding latter, I did some further testing...

Given `IEquatable.Equals(Coordinate)`, `Object.Equals(object)` and `Object.GetHashCode()` are implemented:

- `Equals(c)` (while `c` is a `Coordinate`) always invokes `IEquatable.Equals(Coordinate)`.

**BUT if `c` is `null`, structs and classes seems to behave differently:**

- If `Coordinate` is a class: `IEquatable.Equals(Coordinate)` is invoked
- If `Coordinate` is a struct: `Object.Equals(object)` is invoked

Comment: FYI, mutable structs are a really bad idea.

Comment: Thanks, you are right, I updated my sample code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since you can't implicitly convert `null` to a value type, when you do this:

```
ltown.Equals(null)
```

The method that gets called isn't the `bool Equals(Coordinate other)` you wrote, but the default `Equals(object)` that is inherited from `Object` (well, technically it's the one you get from `ValueType`, but this doesn't really change much in this case). This implementation always returns `false` if you pass `null` to it (as it should).

As a general rule, you should always override that method when implementing `IEquatable<T>`, and you can just delegate to your own implementation:

```
public override bool Equals(object other)
{
    return other is Coordinate coords && Equals(coords);
}
```

And, since you've overriden `Equals`, you now also need to override `GetHashCode`.

---

Now, if you change `Coordinate` to a class, and touch nothing else, you'll get an exception, and that is for two reasons:

1. Since you essentially have two `Equals` overload, overload resolution kicks in and the most appropriate one will be called. As it turns out, the selected overload differs depending on whether `Coordinate` is a reference type or a value type. If you want to know why, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/719546/c-passing-null-to-overloaded-method-which-method-is-called).
2. If you define an `Equals` method for a reference type, it needs to handle `null` values gracefully, that is, it should return `false` in that case (because no value is equal to `null` except `null` itself, and since this is an instance method, `this` cannot be `null`). You of course don't need to do that for value types since they cannot be `null`.

Note that you should also, in all cases, ensure the parameter has the appropriate type. You can combine both checks in one with clever use of the `as` operator:

```
public class A : IEquatable<A>
{
    public bool Equals(A a)
    {
        return a != null && /* other checks */;
    }

    public override bool Equals(object o)
    {
        return Equals(o as A);
    }

    // GetHashCode omitted for brevity
}
```

Comment: You should test that `other` (in your `object`-based overload) is, in fact, a `Coordinate`, if not, return false. Consider using `return (other as Coordinate) != null && ...`

Comment: I updated the answer to explain why it throws for classes.